# Possible to Create Customized App?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have seen that you can download some SP app but I wonder if you can create my own app and sell it? If possible, is there a certain way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MS would like nothing better than for you to write and sell your own SP app. Doing so is a bit tricky though.

You need to decide where your app will be hosted (locally, your server or auto-hosted on Azure) and which apis your app will use.

Some starting points:

- [Apps for SharePoint overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179930.aspx)
- [Build apps for SharePoint](http://goo.gl/2EX1S)
- [Introduction to SharePoint apps](http://goo.gl/48rQP)
- [Apps for Office and SharePoint: Common questions](http://goo.gl/CmRKA)
- [Apps for SharePoint UX design guidelines](http://goo.gl/ZpznY)
- [Sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site](http://goo.gl/ocv8i)
- [Walkthrough: Create a SharePoint-hosted Project Server app](http://goo.gl/3bcHI)